# How to merge multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, array-merge

I have the following case in php

```
$one = array('one' => 1,  2 => array('intro'=> 'something', 'short' => 'short')); 
$two = array('intro' => 'something_new');
$three = array_merge($one,$two);
```

what I wanted to do is to change the one[2][intro] to two[intro]
what it does is append the "two" array into the "one"

How I could change the value of the first array with the second ones by knowing only the key but not in which level is this key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
$one[2] = array_merge($one[2],$two);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
$new_two = array_merge($one[2],$two)
$one[2] = $new_two;
```

Comment: @Nicola For this example would work but what if I don't know where [intro] is in array "one". What I mean is that I dont know if intro is $one[2][intro] or $one[intro] or if it is even deeper in an array...

Comment: @x_maras obviously, your comment is valid for me as well... so, yes, that would be a case (which we could probably solved by searching the array tree before merging)